# CoreData entity like id type

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 methods. I want to make one from it.
Problem is they I can not replace entity type with id, because then I have not entity properties. How can I do it?

```
  + (BOOL)saveGroupImageToDisk:(UIImage*)image toEntity:(GroupEntity *)appEntity withparams:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

   +BOOL)saveImageToDisk:(UIImage*)image toEntity:(WallpostDetailEntity *)wallpostEntityDetail withparams:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `id` is you like just use the accessor methods instead of the property.

```
+(BOOL)saveGroupImageToDisk:(UIImage*)image toEntity:(id)entity withparams:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
{
    [entity setPropertyName:nil];
    ...
}
```

E.g. if you have a properties declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *age;
```

You would access them in the following way:

```
[object setName:@"Bob"];
NSString *name = [object name];

[object setAge:40];
NSInteger age = [object age];
```

All you do is lose the compile time checking that that an instance of that class has that property defined.

Comment: This not working + (BOOL)saveGroupImageToDisk:(UIImage*)image toEntity:(id *)entity withparams:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    [entity setImagePath: @"??"];

Comment: Note the signature I give the `entity` parameter, `id` **not** `id*` :)